# What are the BCS/External List Limitations for ECMA CSOM?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, bcs, external-list

I cannot seem to find any documentation on this topic. Are there any limitations for what I can or cannot do with the JavaScript CSOM in SharePoint Server Standard 2010 External Lists as compared to regular lists? I know that I can read data, but is full CRUD supported? Are there any limitations I need to worry about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the limitations I have encountered is that if you query the external list you need to specify all fields in the ViewFields collection, otherwise you will get the following error:
"The given key was not present in the dictionary'. I have blogged about it here:

[SharePoint: The given key was not present in the dictionary.](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2011/08/given-key-was-not-present-in-dictionary.html).